# clubing RTSP stream to a webpage

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, html5-video, rtsp, rtp

First please forgive me if this question does not make any sense, I am new to media ans streaming world.

I have a question on how to club RTSP stream with a webpage. I am using openRTSP utility for this.

I am able to stream a MKV file using below code:

```
<div id="mtvPlayer"> 
    <embed 
        type="application/x-mplayer2" 
        pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" 
        name="mediaplayer1" 
        ShowStatusBar="true" 
        EnableContextMenu="false" 
        autostart="true" 
        loop="false" 
        src="rtsp://192.168.0.103:8554/test.mkv" 
        width="352px"
        height="288px"
    /> 
</div>
```

## Question:

I have been trying to use openRTSP as a client, however its a command line tool, so I am not able to figure out how and where openRTSP client + browser + plugins will fit in.

With above chunk of code , I can stream video without openRTSP. Now I need to use openRTSP to stream over webpage, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't stream an RTSP stream to a browser directly in a portable way (there are browsers that have VLC plugin which can do this, but again the support is limited). So you need to remux the RTSP stream to a container that is supported by the browser.

Comment: thanks for clarity, If I am not wrong RTSP uses RTP RTCP for streaming over UDP.

Comment: @user5584716, no, RTCP is a protocl that provides QOS information for a   n RTP regardless of the type of transport (TCP/UDP) stream. If you want to embed the RTSP stream in a web page then as I said - either you need to use a browser plugin or deploy a proxy that muxes the RTSP stream into a mp4 or webm streaming container.